# Check in PHP if date_default_timezone_set() has been called

Tags: php, date, timezone

Does anyone know a method in PHP where I can check that `date_default_timezone_set()` has been called in prior code?

I can check for the timezone being set in the php.ini by calling `ini_set()`, but when I use `date_default_timezone_get()` the system either guesses the time for me or returns me the time set and I cannot see how to differentiate between the two.

When the timezone is set in the php.ini I do not need to run `date_default_timezone_set()` at all. When it is not set in php.ini, then some prior code may have set the date time using `date_default_timezone_set()`. In that case, again the code does not need to set the timezone again. But when the timezone is not set, then one must be set. The problem is that `date_default_timezone_get()` does not return an empty value in this case but - depending on the PHP version - either 'UTC' or the local timezone of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that calling `date_default_timezone_set()` will not affect global (`.ini`) setting, so you'll be able to check that via `ini_get()` function:

```
if(date_default_timezone_get()!=ini_get('date.timezone'))
{
   //date_default_timezone_set() was used
}
```

but, if you'll use `ini_set()` - that will not work (if I've understood correctly, you've described this issue in your question) since it will change ini setting for current script instance (but, of cause, not ini-file itself). So, I think, you should not use `ini_set()` then, if you want to differ using `date_default_timezone_set()`

*edit*: if your `date.timezone` is not set in `php.ini`, then you can use `ini_set()` at application's start (so use it only once) - to set this setting.

Comment: This code will always return true when the date is not set in php.ini, regardless of any prior calls to date_default_timezone_set().

Comment: Yes. So in your case it isn't set? (i.e. in php.ini)?

Comment: On some systems it is set, on others it isn't. :)

Comment: @Matijs that is easy - at application's start, check it via `ini_get()` - and, if it's empty, use `ini_set()` then. After this you'll be able to check `date_default_timezone_set()` using in any place

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me Alma, but that still doesn't tell me whether the function date_default_timezone_set() was called by the guy using the library we wrote library or not.

Comment: @Matijs why? Did you tried combination of checking value via `ini_get`/setting it if it's empty via `ini_set`? It works well for me (i.e. after this I can store initial value at application's start and compare it in checkpoint to produce valid `date_default_timezone_set` function call check)

Comment: Darn, you are right. I was so focused on checking the use `date_default_timezone_set` that I overlooked that your solution does exactly what I want without the check. Sorry about that.

Comment: This code may not work at all in some situations. In my test, `ini_get('date.timezone')` results in `""`, but `date_default_timezone_get()` already has a value even when I call it as the first line in my code. I'm looking for an answer to the same question, but this answer will not work on my system.